# Delete route, .remove not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, sequelize.js

I´ve created a route to delete a product but when I try to run it, I get the error `.remove is not a function`. I don't know why this is occurring or how to fix it, I have looked only haven't found anything that works. My route looks like this:

```
orderRouter.delete(
    '/:id',
    isAuth,
    isAdmin,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
        const order = await Orderline.findByPk(req.params.id);
        if (order) {
            const deletedOrder = await order.remove();
            res.send({ message: 'Order Deleted', product: deletedOrder });
        } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'Order Not Found' });
        }
    })
);
```

Any guidance/help is much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is, that the `.remove()` function does not exist on that type. Maybe you are expecting a different thing there?

Comment: Maybe just use `Model.destroy()` here as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402597/sequelize-js-delete-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sequelize ORM, `Instance.remove()` is not a function. Use `Instance.destroy()` instead.

Refer to the documentation about it [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-instances/#deleting-an-instance)

So your fixed code would be:

```
orderRouter.delete(
    '/:id',
    isAuth,
    isAdmin,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
        const order = await Orderline.findByPk(req.params.id);
        if (order) {
            const deletedOrder = await order.destroy();
            res.send({ message: 'Order Deleted', product: deletedOrder });
        } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'Order Not Found' });
        }
    })
);
```